# Naive Bayer Classifier - Do we use dependence structure?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, naive-bayes

If we apply Naive Bayer Classifier and predict an unseen observation just by using the posterior probability calculated with Bayes theorem combined with the naive feature independence assumption, do we neglect all kind of dependence sturcture (e.g. the (co)variance)? Or does that somehow still enter into our prediction? And is precisely this simplification that allows us to apply it on a variety of problems, right?
Thanks!